# Can't fetch flask api on react native expo app running on my android phone

Tags: python, android, react-native, flask, expo

I am running my flask application on localhost and created apis using flask-restful library. I am using my network ip address in the api call. When I call api from react native app using expo, the api is not being called and I am not getting any network request failed error. I have added CORS also in my flask app.

Here is my flask app.py file.

```
from flask_restful import Api
from mobile_resources.events import UserMobile
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})

api.add_resource(UserMobile, '/mobile')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Here is my api method which is simply returning a string

```
from flask import json
from flask_restful import Resource

class UserMobile(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return json.dumps({"data": "test user"})
```

my App.js in react native app calling the api

```
  const getUser = async () => {
        try {
            const URL = "http://192.168.10.22:5000/mobile"
            const response = await fetch(URL, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                }
            })
            let res = await response.json()
            response.ok && res ? 
                setUser(JSON.parse(res).data)
            :
                setUser("")
            setIsValidated(true)
            console.log("User: ", user)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error ", err)
            setUser("")
        }
    }
```

On a side note, with android emulator, using ip address "10.0.2.2" works but with real android phone, none of the ip addresses are working. Please help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution. The solution is to use the host "0.0.0.0" in the flask application. Adding only `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)` was not enough. So, instead I had to run the following command to start flask app on my local machine.

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```